# Product of Laplace transforms with disjoint Region Of Convergence (ROC)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Let the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ be $$X(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)\exp(-st)dt, \ \ \ \ \ s\in\mathbb{C}$$This integral converges when $s \in \text{ROC}_1$. Also suppose that the Laplace transform of $h(t)$ be $H(s)$ which converges when $s\in\text{ROC}_2$. I'm interested in the case $\text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset$. I think in this case the convolution of $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ is divergent, i.e. $$\forall t\in \mathbb{R}: \ \ y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau \ \ \text{diverges}.$$ Or at least it diverges almost surely. I want to find a rigorous proof for this hypothesis. So maybe we should consider a special class of functions such as $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

**Example:** Take $x(t) = \exp(-\alpha t)u(t)$ and $h(t) = \exp(-\alpha t)u(-t)$ where $\alpha \gt 0$ and $u(t)$ denotes the step function. Then we have $$X(s) = \frac{1}{s+\alpha} \ \ \ \text{ROC}_1: \ \Re\{s\}\gt -\alpha, \\ H(s) = \frac{1}{s+\alpha} \ \ \ \text{ROC}_2: \ \Re\{s\}\lt -\alpha.$$ In this case the convolution is divergent: $$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-\alpha \tau)u(\tau)\exp(-\alpha (t-\tau))u(-(t-\tau))d\tau = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \exp(-\alpha t)u(\tau - t)d\tau \\ = \exp(-\alpha t)\int_{t}^{+\infty}d\tau = \infty.$$

Also if we consider $h(t) = \exp(-\alpha't)u(-t)$ where $\alpha' \not = \alpha$ the same steps show that $y(t)$ converges when $\alpha' \lt \alpha$, so $\text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2: \ \Re\{s\} \in (-\alpha , -\alpha')$.

**Related question:** [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71057/disjoint-rocs-of-input-and-system-function) question has been asked previously (for discrete-time signals and $\mathcal{Z}$-transform) but Matt L.'s answer doesn't contain a rigorous proof.

Comment: @AndyWalls Yes maybe. I asked the question here because I guessed Matt L. might have a proof.

Comment: I agree with that. The answer I gave was just looking from a high level conceptual standpoint. A thorough derivation is probably more suited for the math SE

Comment: It seems that migration can't be done currently since the question has a bounty.

Comment: It seems to me your assumptions imply at least one of the Fourier transforms of $x(t)$ or $h(t)$ doesn't exist since at most one of the two can converge along the imaginary axis where $\Re(s)=0$ (i.e. where $s=i \omega t \land t\in\mathbb{R}$ in which case the two-sided Laplace transform is equivalent to the Fourier transform). Is convolution even valid under this condition?

Comment: @StevenClark I'm not sure. Is it possible to prove that the convolution is divergent in that case? I know there are many sufficient conditions for the convergence of convolution but I don't know any necessary condition.

Comment: It would seem to violate (or at least be inconsistent with) the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html) seems to imply convolution applies to Schwartz functions, whereas [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Domain_of_definition) seems to imply more relaxed conditions even going so far as to say "Conditions for the existence of the convolution may be tricky, since a blow-up in $g$ at infinity can be easily offset by sufficiently rapid decay in $f$."

Comment: @StevenClark I've added an answer. It may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Willie Wong's great answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/463341/94522) shows that it's possible to construct uncountably many counterexamples. Let $S = \{ (-2)^k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}, 0\lt \epsilon \lt \frac14$ and define the function$$\chi(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & \exists s\in S, \quad |t-s| < \epsilon \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$Also let $x(t) = h(t) = \chi(t)$. It can be [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864858/finding-the-region-of-convergence-for-the-bilateral-laplace-transform) that in this case $\text{ROC}_1 = \text{ROC}_2 = \text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset$ and the function $\tau \mapsto g(\tau, t-\tau)$ defined by $g(\tau , t-\tau) = \chi(\tau)\chi(t-\tau)$ [has compact support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863287/proving-a-function-has-a-compact-support) for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$. This shows that for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ the convolution converges. If we want to have examples for the case $\text{ROC}_1 \not = \emptyset$ and $\text{ROC}_2 \not = \emptyset$, we can consider $x(t) = \exp(-\eta|t|)\chi(t)$ and $h(t) = \exp(-\eta|t| + 5\eta t)\chi(t)$. In this case [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864858/finding-the-region-of-convergence-for-the-bilateral-laplace-transform) $\text{ROC}_1: \Re(s') \in (-\eta , \eta)$ and $\text{ROC}_2: \Re(s') \in (4\eta , 6\eta)$, so still $\text{ROC}_1 \cap \text{ROC}_2 = \emptyset$ holds. Since the factors $\exp(-\eta|t|)$ and $\exp(-\eta|t| + 5\eta t)$ are always positive, they can't change the support of $g(\tau , t - \tau)$ and so the convolution is well-defined for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure if this is as thorough of an answer as you are looking for, but my thoughts are something like this.

Convolution needs BIBO stability for the integral to converge, ie

\begin{equation}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\alpha\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is some finite constant.

In the Laplace domain, for a function to be BIBO stable, the ROC must contain the imaginary axis. The pole location requirements differ for causal, anticausal, and non-causal, but all must contain the imaginary axis in the ROC to converge. If the ROCs are disjoint, then *at most* one of the functions’ ROCs contains the imaginary axis. This implies one of the functions violates the absolute integrability criterion, which would lead to a divergent convolution.

Additionally, in general the ROC of two Laplace domain functions multiplied together is the intersection of the individual functions’ ROCs. A disjoint intersection between the ROCs implies there is no value where both functions converge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you meant $$\begin{equation}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\alpha\end{equation}$$

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, I was thinking of something else at the same time. Fixed it.

Comment: I've added an answer. It may be interesting for you.