# Proving a function has a compact support

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to understand [Willie Wong's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/463341/94522) which shows that for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $g(\tau , t - \tau)$ has a compact support, i.e., the set $A_t = \{ \tau \in \mathbb{R}: g(\tau , t - \tau) = 1\}$ is bounded. Let $S = \{ (-2)^k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and choose $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$. Define $$\chi(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & \exists s\in S, \quad |t-s| < \epsilon \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ and $g(x,y) = \chi(x) \chi(y)$. It's clear that $g(\tau , t - \tau) = 1$ is equivalent to $$\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: |\tau - (-2)^k| \lt \epsilon \ \  \text{and} \ \   \exists l \in \mathbb{N}:|t-\tau - (-2)^l|\lt \epsilon.$$ So we have the implication, $$g(\tau , t - \tau) = 1 \implies \exists k,l \in \mathbb{N}: |t - ((-2)^k+(-2)^l)| \lt 2\epsilon$$ and its contraposition $$\forall k,l \in \mathbb{N}: |t - ((-2)^k+(-2)^l)| \ge 2\epsilon \implies g(\tau , t - \tau) = 0.$$ So we should suppose that $$\exists k_0,l_0 \in \mathbb{N}: |t - ((-2)^{k_0}+(-2)^{l_0})| \lt 2\epsilon \tag{1}$$ and check when $g(\tau , t - \tau) = 1$ occurs or equivalently, $$\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: |\tau - (-2)^k| \lt \epsilon \ \  \text{and} \ \   \exists l \in \mathbb{N}:|t-\tau - (-2)^l|\lt \epsilon. \tag{2}$$ I don't know how to proceed further. It's obvious that we should use $(1)$ and $(2)$ to prove that the set of $\tau$'s is bounded but I don't see how to do it. It seems that Willie Wong has used the following fact for that purpose:

> $(-2)^k + (-2)^l = (-2)^m + (-2)^n$ if and only if either $\{k,\ell\} = \{m,n\}$ or $k = \ell = \min(m,n) - 1 = \max(m,n) - 2$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the formal write up actually doesn't 100% correspond to the intuition in the picture. But it is close enough. (See my other answer for the intuition.)

#### Case 1: $t$ is such that $g(\tau, t-\tau)\equiv 0$

Nothing to do here

#### Case 2: $t$ is such that for some $\tau$, $g(\tau,t-\tau) = 1$

By your equation (1), you have $| t - ((-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{\ell_0})| < 2 \epsilon$. You are looking for $\tau$ such that equation (2) holds, which using equation (1) would require

$$ |\tau - (-2)^{k}| < \epsilon, \quad | (-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{\ell_0} - \tau - (-2)^\ell| < 3 \epsilon $$

which implies (by triangle inequality)

$$ | (-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{\ell_0} - (-2)^\ell - (-2)^k | < 4 \epsilon $$

Now suppose $\epsilon < \frac14$, then as we are looking on the LHS at differences between integers, for the difference to be less than 1 the term has to be zero. Hence we must have

$$ (-2)^{k_0} + (-2)^{\ell_0} - (-2)^\ell - (-2)^k = 0 \tag{A}$$

By the "fact" about powers of $(-2)$ I proved for you, for a fixed $(k_0,\ell_0)$ this equation has finitely many (in fact at most 3) solutions.

Hence a *necessary condition* for both equations (1) and (2) to hold is that $\tau$ is within $\epsilon < \frac14$ of $(-2)^k$, where $(k,\ell)$ is one of the no more than 3 solutions to equation $A$.

This shows that the set of $\tau$ satisfying the requirement is bounded.

Comment: Great, thanks. By case 1 you mean $$\forall k,l \in \mathbb{N}: |t - ((-2)^k+(-2)^l)| \ge 2\epsilon,$$ right? I think this corresponds to the case $\mathrm{dist}(t, T) \ge 2 \epsilon$ in your previous answer.

Comment: Yes. ..........

Answer (score 1):

I've already given you quite a bit of details in the other answer. I think what you are having trouble with is the visualization. So let me add a picture and talk a bit about the proof using it.

[image]

The picture shown above is a plot of the function $g(x,y)$. The **teal squares** are where $g(x,y) = 1$; I've set $\epsilon = 1/4$ for this picture (which is small enough for the result to hold, but for writing up a proof in words it is more convenient to use something even smaller like $1/10$ so you don't have to worry about applying Pythagorean theorem and such). At the middle of the picture you see a square with cross hairs, that is the square corresponding to $k = \ell = 0$, so $x \approx y \approx 1$.

Given a fixed $t$, the function $\tau \mapsto g(\tau, t-\tau)$ can be thought of as a cross section of the function $g$ along a line with slope $-1$ (the line $x + y = t$). The compact support property is the same as saying that the line intersects finitely many squares. I've marked 4 such $t$ values in the picture.

- In **blue** is the case $t = 0$. This is the "generic case" where the line doesn't intersect any of the teal squares at all. In this case $g(\tau,t-\tau)$ is identically zero.
- In **purple** is the case $t = -10$. Notice that this line intersects two squares. (It will also not intersect any further squares outside of the plotted region.)
- In **red** are the cases $t = 2$ and $t = 8$. Notice that they each intersect 3 squares.

So now let me explain aspects of the proof.

#### Reduction to integers

Each square can be labelled by $(k,\ell)$, where $(x,y) = ((-2)^k, (-2)^\ell)$ is the center of the square.

We can partition the $\mathbb{N}^2 = \{(k,\ell)\}$ into equivalence classes, with each class corresponding to those $(k,\ell)$ with the same $(-2)^k + (-2)^\ell$ sum.

From the picture it should be intuitive that as long as $\epsilon$ is small enough (in fact, as long as $\epsilon < \frac34 \sqrt{2}$ is good enough), it is impossible for a single $x +y = t$ line to pass through squares of different classes. So whether $g(\tau,t-\tau)$ has compact support reduces to whether each equivalence class has only finitely many members.

#### The two different types of intersections

The difference between the **red** and **purple** lines can be summarized thus: in the **purple** case $t / 2$ is **not** a power of $(-2)$. So it can only be written as $(-2)^k + (-2)^\ell$ for $k \neq \ell$. And the elementary number theory fact that I proved for you tells you that for each such $t$, only two solutions are available (basically you are allowed to swap $k$ and $\ell$).

In the **red** case you have that $t / 2$ **is a power** of $(-2)$, or $t = 2(-2)^m$. In this case, there are three possibilities for the $(k,\ell)$ squares, either $k = \ell = m$, or $k = m + 2$ and $\ell = m +1$, or $k = m + 1$ and $\ell = m + 2$.

(As illustration, the purple curve shown in the picture passes through $(k,\ell) \in \{(1,3), (3,1)\}$; the top most red curve passes through $(k,\ell) \in \{(2,2), (3,4), (4,3)\}$.

Comment: The intuitive perspective which you gave was really fabulous! I don’t know how to thank you. If you don't mind I'll add a bounty and after that accept your answer. The only part of your replies that's still unclear to me is multiplying by $e^{-\eta |t|}$ (in order to have $\text{ROC} \not = \emptyset)$. If we consider complex Laplace transform and set $x(t) = e^{-\eta |t|} \chi(t), h(t) = e^{-\eta|t| + 5 \eta t}\chi(t)$ it seems to me that ROCs are still empty (because it's similar to the case $x(t) = h(t) = \chi(t)$ and the integral has an explicit form which involves a divergent series).

Comment: The function $x(t) \exp(-st) = \chi(t) \exp(-\eta |t| - s t)$. Its modulus is strictly less than $\exp(- \eta|t| - \Re(s) t)$. When $t < 0$, convergence requires $\eta - \Re(s) < 0$. When $t > 0$, convergence requires $-\eta - \Re(s) < 0$. In other words, as long as $\eta \in (-\Re(s), \Re(s))$, the integrand to the Laplace transform is dominated by an exponentially decaying function (both positive and negative $t$), so is integrable. (The absolute value of $t$ that shows up is crucial! If you propagate it carefully you see that the series form also converges.)

Comment: Indeed you are right, as always. I tried to do the calculations in detail and asked it as a proof verification [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864858/finding-the-region-of-convergence-for-the-bilateral-laplace-transform). My calculations showed that the ROC for $h(t) = e^{-\eta|t| + 5 \eta t}\chi(t)$ is $(4\eta,6\eta)$ not $(-6\eta,-4\eta)$ as you wrote previously. I would appreciate your help if you point out my mistake about this or about any other detail.

Comment: It is quite possible I dropped a negative sign in my original answer/comment to you. If you computed in the same way and found that $(4\eta,6\eta)$ is the correct answer, I'd believe you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all of the time you spent on the my questions.